# Quote a macro preprocessor using -D

Tags: c, bash, macros, c-preprocessor

We can use the output of a command (with flags) as macro pre-procesor (eg. `uname --kernel-name`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define version(v) #v
#define VERSION(v) version(v)

int main(void)
{
    printf("Version: %s\n", VERSION(kernel_name));
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled using:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -o demo demo.c -Dkernel_name=$(uname --kernel-name)
```

Output:

```
Version: Linux
```

But this fail when macro begins with `#` (eg. `uname --kernel-version`):

```
david@debian:~$ uname --kernel-version
#1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1
```

Because you can not define a preprocessor starting with `#`

```
#define SOMETHING #something /* error: stray ‘#’ in program */
```

Is there  way to quote the output of command?

```
"#1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1"
```

in order to get a valid input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.

Replace

```
-Dkernel_name=$(uname --kernel-name)
```

with

```
-Dkernel_name="\"$(uname --kernel-name)\""
```

This works because the `-D` flag is equivalent to a define. So `-Dvar=val` is equivalent to having a `#define var val` in your source.

When you do `-Dkernel_name="\"$(uname --kernel-name)\""`, your shell converts the define option value to equal `"#1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1"` - one set of quotes for your shell and another for your actual program. This saves you from having to stringify too.

Comment: Stupid me!!, works like a charm, I was trying `""$(uname --kernel-name)""`

Comment: Yup, you forgot to escape :)